# Rails Friendly Id - Couldn't find Category with id=electronics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I'm trying to develop a app in Ruby on Rails 4.0 (already used older versions of this incredible framework) and I having some troubles.

I installed the [FriendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem and I think everything is okay, but I'm receiving errors when I try to test my app.

If I go to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/categories/1`, this works. But when I click in "edit" in this page, or just go to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/categories/electronics` (that's the slugged name of category with ID 1), I receive the following error:

```
Couldn't find Category with id=electronics
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_category
   @category = Category.find(params[:id])  #Here's pointed the error
end
```

### Category Model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

    # Validations
    validates_uniqueness_of :name, :case_sensitive => false

end
```

### Category Controller:

(generated by scaffold for test purposes)

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /categories
  # GET /categories.json
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  # GET /categories/1
  # GET /categories/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /categories/new
  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  # GET /categories/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /categories
  # POST /categories.json
  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1
  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /categories/1
  # DELETE /categories/1.json
  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

### Migration:##

(I added friendlyId after create the Category table, but I think is okay)

```
class AddColumnToCategory < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :categories, :slug, :string
    add_index :categories, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

### Routes:

```
resources :categories
```

Hope you can help me. **What I'm doing wrong in Rails 4.0?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Check the doc](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/#Docs), friendly id stopped hacking `find` method (for the greater good), you now have to do:

```
# Change Category.find to Category.friendly.find in your controller
Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: I must change every .find() in my controller or just in the set_category? Another thing, what's exactly "set_category", can you post a reference link to this 'thing'?

Comment: every single `find` related to a friendly id

Comment: no, this is generated by scaffold and I don't know why this method exist

Comment: This works, thanks (: (But still don't know why this method exist)

Comment: oh ok well, it's just a convenient method to avoid duplication

Comment: Yes, it works well and now we have to make change in single method of each model.

Answer (score 12):

You can now use:

`extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: [:finders]`

in your model.

Comment: Thank you, this is a better solution then the accepted answer